# Netbook Ubuntu can I install something better now

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-netbook

Running Ubuntu on a netbook but lets face it its not very exciting. Can I run 11.10 on a netbook N455 its a 1.6hz 1mb.
Can I install 11.10 or something better (at least a 10.xx vesrion) rather than using the netbook version which is a bit basic. I see that netbook version is now discontinued.. W7 got corrupted when I installed so I want to be sure that new ubuntu wont make things worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The netbook and desktop edition of Ubuntu have been merged into the desktop edition, that's how we ended up with Unity (which would be great if it was a bit more snappy and stable). You could try to install Ubuntu 11.10 on that computer, though I'd recommend you use the "2D" environment (Unity 2D). If it doesn't work out you could always try a more lightweight Ubuntu derrative like Xubuntu or Elementary OS.
The advantage of most Linux distributions is that you can try them out from a LiveCD first to see if you like them (though I recommend putting them onto a USB drive (MultiSystem is a good application for that), CD's are a bit slow).

Comment: Thanks I wasnt aware there was a 2d version. I have 11.10 32 and 64b already downloaded for other laptops. Do you think it will be ok to try them on there first to see. Would be nice to have cloud and all that stuff. Is it enough just to copy the cd files onto a pendrive? Thanks

Comment: Yeah you can use 2d by clicking on the gear at the logon screen and clicking unity 2d its a lot faster (and a lot uglier)

Comment: Oh so its just a logon change like loading the light version of the full verseion installed?

Comment: Yes. And to be able to boot Ubuntu from a pendrive you need to use an application like MultiSystem. The site's in French, so here's a direct link to the installation script: http://liveusb.info/multisystem/install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar.bz2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. It's not going to be super speedy, but there's nothing stopping you. You might want to try out Lubuntu, a lightweight, fast Ubuntu-based desktop designed especially for limited-resources machines like netbooks. Unfortunately, you sacrifice some eye-candy in the process, but for someone like me, that's okay.

Comment: Heh thanks the netbook is forlight travelling not for power. I like standard ubunto as I am used to it. Would you recomend a particular version of ubuntu  is 11.10 ok on a netbook if not I have cd of 10.04..w7 got screwed and I will have to look at that some stage (blue screen)

Comment: Well, 11.10 will work just as well as any other. There were speed improvements. Could You mark my or Robin's answer as answer? Click the grayed-out greeen checkmark under the arrows in the question to do so.

Comment: Guys you both answered excellently I can only click 1 so I clicked Robin as his answer is a little more complete. Thanks and have a good holiday..Antony

Comment: dang... at least I tried.

Comment: hmmm trying to try 11.10 with the cd on an external drive. cd boots but even if I hold down shift it runs into normal boot instead of installation try screen. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: make this into a new question

Answer (score 0):

That computer should be able to run any version of Ubuntu. If you have a memory stick and a good internet connection, I'd recommend that you try all of the official ones; Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

### [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)

Is the most popular version and is the one with most support. 
If you want to know how 11.10 looks you can take the [tour](http://www.ubuntu.com/tour/)!

### [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu#A11.10)

Is similar to Ubuntu but has a lighter interface which is suitable if you want to spare the weight put on your computer.

*The performance that you experience is not totally down to the system. The applications you use will have an effect.*